# VueJs v-for renders divs but not table rows?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, rendering

I'm having trouble understanding why this is happening! So, this block of code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" v-for="rows in data.Rows"> {{ rows }} </div>
</div>
```

Will render all the rows in the object. 
But, when I use the same syntax in a table instead like this:

```
<table>
   <tr v-for="rows in data.Rows"> {{ rows }} </tr>
</table>
```

I get the error:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "rows" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
```

How come there are issues in using the v-for like this in a table? I want a table to display the data as it better suits the purpose in this case. Othewise I would have chosen divs instead of table rows, but I would love for this to works. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Where does this template live? Is it directly inside an HTML file?

Comment: can you please  update the question with sample object in row.Rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use that template directly within an HTML file (as opposed to a template string or SFC) it will be parsed by the browser before it gets to Vue. Browsers are fussy about tables and what elements are allowed inside which other elements.

The example below shows how the browser will parse your template into DOM nodes. Notice how the `{{ rows }}` gets moved:

```js
let html = document.getElementById('app').innerHTML

html = html.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;')

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = html
```

```css
#app {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="rows in data.Rows"> {{ rows }} </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<pre id="output">
</pre>
```

It is this mangled version of the template that Vue is trying to run and as you can see `{{ rows }}` has been moved outside the `v-for`, causing the error.

The official documentation covers this here:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats

The solution would just be to include a `<td>` in your template:

```html
<table>
   <tr v-for="rows in data.Rows">
     <td>{{ rows }}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That makes sense... I have learned something new today! Didn't find the documentation on vuejs.org, but I will read into it more. Works like a charm now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly use "rows" property inside tr tag, you need td tag

> like this

```
<table>
    <tr class="row" v-for="rows in data.Rows"> <td>{{ rows }} </td></tr>
  </table>
```

working codepen here: https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/dyyVybK